# How do I access combo box inside another interface panel in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a parent form, which contains panels that calls different user control.
For example, the file is something like this.

Form1.cs -> Contains the main panel

selectioninterface.cs -> Contains a combobox which dynamically changes the panel(interface1 or interface2)

interface1.cs
interface2.cs -> These contains a separate panel which form1.cs calls inside its panel.

I am currently looping through the form1 panel using this.

```
    foreach(Control control in panel.Controls) {
        if(control.GetType() == typeof(selectioninterface))
        {

        }
}
```

I got this part, but I need to access the textbox and combobox information located inside the interface1 and interface2 panels. How do I access them?

Comment: Cast the controls to the correct type and make the controls public so you can just acces them from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
this.Controls.Find("YourControlName", true);
```

this will return a control collection if specified control exists

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that define event in interface and handle the event in parent form. In event pass the value as argument.

```
public delegate void MyEventHandler(object value);

event MyEventHandler MyEvent;
```

and raise the event when the control value is changed.